# Dotnet API returns empty arrays for properties of anonymous object

Tags: c#, json, .net, api, json.net

I am trying to get a json document out of my CosmosDB. This document has a property which can be different from document to document. My definition of the Class is the following:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "template")]
public object Template { get; set; }

[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "templateName")]
public string TemplateName { get; set; }
```

The Template property is an object that has properties and more objects that can have nested objects and so on. This is unstructured so I can't define it with classes.

When I get a document from the cosmosDb I can see in the debugger that I get the entire document and everything looks good. For some reason though, when I look at the http response my API throws out the document changes.

Here the code I use to get the document out of the Cosmos DB:

```
try
{
    ItemResponse<Domain.Models.ArmTemplate> response = await container.ReadItemAsync<Domain.Models.ArmTemplate>(id, new PartitionKey(id));
    return response.Resource;
}
catch(CosmosException ex) when (ex.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
{ 
    return null;
}
```

This returns the correct ArmTemplate object and everything looks good.
The returned object then gets returned to the controller which returns it as the response:

```
[HttpGet("{id}"]
public async Task<ArmTemplate> GetArmTemplate(string id)
{
    var armTemplate = await armTemplateService.GetArmTemplateAsyncById(id);
    return armTemplate
}
```

Again when I look at the value of `armTemplate` in the debugger everything looks good.
Then when I look at the json I get returned from the API it looks completely different.

I paste a part of the response and the expected response since the document is not that small:

expected response:

```json
{      
    "templateName": "resourceGroup",
    "template": {
          "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2018-05-01/subscriptionDeploymentTemplate.json#",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
          "metadata": {},
          "parameters": {
                "rgName": {
                "type": "string",
                "metadata": {
                    "description": "Name of the resourceGroup to create"
                }
            },
```

Actual Response:

```json
{
   "templateName": "resourceGroup",
    "template": {
       "$schema": [],
       "contentVersion": [],
       "metadata": [],
       "parameters": [
        [
            [
                [
                    []
                ],
```

I am quite sure that this is some parsing issue but I do not know how to fix it.
If anyone know how to fix this any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not sure what you mean the first code block contains the class ArmTemplate @PeterCsala

Comment: Apologize, my mistake. You are right.

Comment: I notice that `Template` is declared as an `object`.  Is there any chance you deserialized your initial JSON using Json.NET, and then attempted to serialize it with System.Text.Json?  Json.NET deserializes properties declared as `object` into an appropriate subclass of `JToken`  (here `JObject`) and System.Text.Json does not know how to serialize LINQ to JSON `JToken` classes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @dbc I was able to find the solution, it was in fact a mixup of newtonsoft.json and text.json. As soon as I told the cosmos client to use text.json it started to work. I followed these instructions to do so:
[https://ankitvijay.net/2021/06/20/custom-json-serializer-settings-with-cosmos-db-sdk/](https://@dbc%20thats%20it!%20I%20changed%20the%20cosmosdb%20client%20to%20use%20system.text.json%20as%20described%20here%20https://ankitvijay.net/2021/06/20/custom-json-serializer-settings-with-cosmos-db-sdk/)